# How can you constrain values to be positive when fitting a model?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model, constrained-regression

I'm currently fitting a model using maximum likelihood estimation on biological data (electroencephalography). Basically, I'm fitting normal distributions to several subsets of data (experimental conditions), and I want to evaluate how the mean and standard deviation will vary across them.

Say I have 3 subsets 1,2, and 3, that are mutually exclusive. Given my hypotheses, I expect data to be normally distributed in each condition, the mean to increase from subset 1 to 3, and the reverse to occur for the standard deviation. I would like to test for this. Here is what I did:

My mean is modeled by:

$\mu_{subsetNumber} = \Phi_{mu}(subsetNumber, parameters_{mu})$

where $\Phi_{mu}$ is a sigmoid function with several free parameters (upper bound, lower bound, slope, and midpoint).

For the standard deviation, I wanted to simply use a linear relationship because I have fewer assumptions about how this metric should vary:

$\sigma_{subsetNumber} = subsetNumber *a + b$

Where $a$ and $b$ are free parameters.

I then computed the maximum log-likelihood that my whole dataset is modeled by gaussian distributions with varying $\mu_{subsetNumber}$ and $\sigma_{subsetNumber}$ using the Nelder-Mead optimization algorithm.

But because I allow for negative variances when I use a linear function, which makes no sense, I often end up with non-sensical fits and imaginary maximum log-likelihoods.

I originally resolved this by writing:
$\sigma_{subsetNumber} = \Phi_{sigma}(subsetNumber, parameters_{sigma})$

where $\Phi_{sigma}$ is a sigmoid function with several free parameters (upper bound, lower bound, slope, and its midpoint being the same as the mean's). I used this function because if the variance increases or decreases somewhat linearly, this can be modeled by a sigmoid function with a shallow slope. Furthermore, it makes sense for the variance in my biological data to be bounded between reasonable values.

I've been suggested to find a solution to keep the linear relationship between $\sigma$ and $subsetNumber$ because it is simpler. It was suggested to me to use the absolute value of $\sigma$, or make negative values impossible, rather than adding a bunch of parameters to my model. Can someone explain to me whether this last approach is correct, and could it tamper with the algorithm's well-functioning? Also, wouldn't that lead to a potentially non-monotonic variation in standard deviation?

What are my options are for modeling a variable that cannot be negative besides what I proposed above?

Comment: Please say more about your data and what you are trying to accomplish. What is the nature of the data? Are values necessarily positive? Are subsets mutually exclusive or overlapping? Are normal distributions appropriate? What do you mean by "the constraint that the variance will decrease across subsets"? How do you know that the constraint can be met? Why can you assume that a linear or a logistic function might describe the change of the SD among subsets? Say more about what you are trying to accomplish; you might get ideas about how to proceed with alternate, better approaches.

Comment: Have you considered formulating it as a constrained problem and solving it with an appropriate solver ?

Comment: I updated the problem with a clearer explanation. It was, indeed, a bit under-detailed and some parts were imprecise. I don't know of any solvers that can help me formulate a constrained problem, could you point me towards an example? Thank you

Comment: It is only the variance that should be positive? Then reparametrize, write the model functions in terms of $log(\sigma)$ and then you can use unconstrained optimization in that new parameter.

Comment: Yes, it is only the variance. I'm not sure what reparameterizing actually means, I'm sorry. Should I say that $\sigma$ has a linear relationship to my predictor variable but actually fit its log? That doesn't seem to make much sense. Can you point me to an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so, thanks to the comment made by [kjetil b halvorsen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen) I got it working. Re-expressing:
$\sigma_{log} = log(subsetNumber*a + b)$

and

$\sigma_{subsetNumber} = exp(sigma_{log})$

bounds $\sigma_{subsetNumber}$ in positive space, but keeps it linear!

Thank you all for the useful comments.